# How to perform an $or query in Mongoose/MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to get a variety of items in my MongoDB collection based on an `$or` statement.

Following [these official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/query/or/) the query I have constructed looks acceptable, yet the first `$gt` statement is not being fulfilled. It is returning items that have a `quantity` equal to zero.

```
let query = {};

query.$or = [ { 'quantity': { $gt: 0 } }, { type: { $in: [ITEM_TYPE_A, ITEM_TYPE_B] } }];

db.Items.find(query).then( res => res)
```

Could it be the `dot` syntax appending a new key/value pair to the query object? Unfortunetly this query is just one of many that get appended to the `query` object based on `if` statements. Ex. `if (something) query.field = value`

Comment: can you post your dataset? (or a snippet of it)

Comment: Are you sure you want an Or? If you want both conditions to being fulfilled then use an $and.

Comment: How does `query` look like. Can you add a example (JSON)?

Comment: Updated code snippet to show where `query` comes from. I found a solution below.

Comment: @Chromz I definitely need an `$or`

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out why, but using the `Object.assign` method fixed my query.

**Instead of:**

```
query.$or = [ { 'quantity': { $gt: 0 } }, { type: { $in: [ITEM_TYPE_A, ITEM_TYPE_B] } }]
```

**I did:**

```
query = Object.assign({}, query, { $or: { 'quantity': { $gt: 0 } }, { type: { $in: [ITEM_TYPE_A, ITEM_TYPE_B]}
```

Comment: Its because you cant use a special sign in a name of a field like that, you either need to `object.assign` like you did, `query["$or"] = ... and let mongo parse the string or . `query = {"$or": ... }`

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of following

```
let query = {};

query = {...query,$or:[ { 'quantity': { $gt: 0 } }, { type: { $in: [ITEM_TYPE_A, ITEM_TYPE_B] } }]};
```

or

```
query = Object.assign({}, query, { $or: [ { 'quantity': { $gt: 0 } }, { type: { $in: [ITEM_TYPE_A, ITEM_TYPE_B] } }]});
```

or

```
query["$or"] = [ { 'quantity': { $gt: 0 } }, { type: { $in: [ITEM_TYPE_A, ITEM_TYPE_B] } }];
```